# Max Value of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, max

I have this Array

```
  Array
(
    [2014-08-14] => Array
        (
            [18:00:00] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 15.36
                            [avail_clean] => 5
                            [avail_noclean] => 6
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 17.35
                            [avail_clean] => 2
                            [avail_noclean] => 3
                        )

                )

            [19:00:00] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 15.36
                            [avail_clean] => 5
                            [avail_noclean] => 6
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 17.35
                            [avail_clean] => 2
                            [avail_noclean] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How can I get the following for 6 & 7 seperately:
- Sum of price
- max of avail_clean
- max of avail_noclean

I got that far for the price:

```
foreach ($bookable as $date=>$key) {
    foreach ($key as $time=>$key2) {
        foreach($key2 as $room=>$key3){
            foreach($key3 as $price=>$key4){
                if($price == "price"){
                    if(isset($sumRoom[$room]['total'])){
                        $sumRoom[$room]['total'] += $key4;
                    }else{
                        $sumRoom[$room]['total'] = $key4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Gives me this

```
Array(
[6] => Array
    (
        [total] => 30,72
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [total] => 34,7
    )
```

)

But what about the max(), where should I put that?

Comment: you need to clarify your goal. what do you mean by max? you want to get the highest `avail_clean` and `avail_noclean` number?, you already got you sum, should be the same path, if not initialized assign it, then under the loop just check if the current number is higher, if yes then reassign

Comment: I'd like to get the max of avail_clean and the max of avail_noclean. Isn't the "loop compare" method the "dirty" one? Shouldn't I use max() for the more elegant way?

Comment: if that's what you want, then just before the last inner loop map all the `avail_clean` and `avail_clean` then use `max()`

Comment: Have you found answer? If not, you can check my answer once!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($bookable as $date=>$times) {
    foreach ($times as $time=>$rooms) {
        foreach($rooms as $room=>$options){ $sumRoom[$room]['total'] = 0;
            foreach($options as $option=>$value){

                if($option == "price"){
                    $sumRoom[$room]['total'] += $value;
                }
                if($option == "avail_clean"){
                    $avail_clean[$room][] = $value;
                }
                if($option == "avail_noclean"){
                    $avail_noclean[$room][] = $value;
                }

            }
            $sumRoom[$room]['avail_clean_max'] = max($avail_clean[$room]);
            $sumRoom[$room]['avail_noclean'] = max($avail_noclean[$room]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've edited my answer.. I've merged all in one array i.e. `$sumRoom`

Comment: tried to use before edit and edited myself to the same outcome (more or less). Works like a charm now! Thanks