# Custom Array Sorting in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a 5 level nested array and I want to sort it in a custom way.

After some sorting the structure is:

```
[shortcode1] => Array
    (
        [country1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 10
                [revenue_value] => 11
            )

    )

[shortcode2] => Array
    (
        [country1] => Array
            (
                [count] => 24
                [revenue_value] => 52
            )

    )
[shortcode3] => Array
    (
        [country2] => Array
            (
                [count] => 25
                [revenue_value] => 52
            )

    )
```

The result I want is to group the array by country and have it like:

```
[country1] => Array
(
    [count] => 34            // sum of all counts of country1
    [revenue_value] => 63    // sum of all revenue_values of country1
)
[country2] => Array
(
    [count] => 25            // sum of all counts of country2
    [revenue_value] => 52    // sum of all revenue_values of country2
)
```

This is my code so far:

```
        <?php foreach ($country_shortcode as $shortcode): 
            $count = 0; 
            $revenue = 0;
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($shortcode as $country=>$value): ?>
                <?php 
                    $count += $value['count'];
                    $revenue += $value['revenue_value'];
                    $country_sum[$country] = array(
                            'count' => $count,
                            'revenue' => $revenue,
                        ); 
                    ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But it only displays the last value per country

**UPDATE + ANSWER:**

This is the updated code that does exactly what I wanted to do.

```
        $country_data;
        <?php foreach ($country_shortcode as $shortcode): 
            $count = 0; 
            $revenue = 0;
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($shortcode as $country=>$value): ?>
                <?php 
                    if (!isset($country_sum[$country])) $country_sum[$country] = array('count' => 0, 'revenue'=>0);
                    $country_sum[$country]['count'] += $value['count'];
                    $country_sum[$country]['revenue'] += $value['revenue_value'];
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: [Check similar issue link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25301224/2679536)

Comment: this is not sorting. It's some kind of re-organizing/re-grouping the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too easy... just loop over the array creating a new one

```
foreach ($array as $sub) {
  foreach ($sub as $countryName => $data) {
    if (!isset($result[$countryName])) {
       $result[$countryName] = ['count' => 0, 'revenue_value' => 0];
    }
    $result[$countryName]['count'] += $data['count'];
    $result[$countryName]['revenue_value'] += $data['revenue_value'];
  }
}
```

Comment: the !isset($result[$countryName]) was the thing I was looking for. Thanks man for the help.